# asterisk emailing status update

Tags: email, asterisk

i am running asterisk in my system and i would like to get an email everytime that changes the status of the
asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | grep trunk_name

i do not want to poll the script in a periodic way to ask for the status. I would like to get an email everytime the status changes.
i can send messages from my system with the following:
echo "This is Content" | mail -s "This is subject" userA@ISPmail.org

at the moment all i do is to periodically ask the system (cron, bashscript) to send me an email with the current status.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get it is use specialized software like fail2ban or nagios/centreon.

You just need create filter(for fail2ban - regexp and remove banning part) and say program to watch asterisk log.

Answer (score 0):

John,

The best way to do with is with a Ruby or PHP application that loops once a second and taps the AMI port for the status information.  You then parse and issue a status email if required.

Checkout:

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239
http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-AMI.html

That should give you the info to get started.